# Switch to previous viewport with compiz

Tags: compiz, cinnamon, workspace-switcher

I use cinnamon with compiz and I have 12 viewports.

Sometimes I get a mail or message so the viewport switches to the mail viewport. Thats ok.
The problem is that I forget the viewport I was originally. 
Is there some kind of variable like $OLDPWD but then for viewports.
Then I can use "xdotool set_desktop_viewport x y" to switch back. 
That would really give me the feeling I know what I'm doing.

Comment: CTRL+ALT+ArrowKey is the typical shortcut for Compiz.  You can try using [Compiz Config Settings Manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=compizconfig-settings-manager) to enable/change this functionality.

Comment: That is not my question.

Answer (score 0):

Put this script in the "Sessions and Startup" > "Application Autostart"

```
#!/bin/bash
touch ~/.olddesktop
echo 0,0 >  ~/.olddesktop
echo 0,0 >> ~/.olddesktop
while true
do 
    ODT=$(head -n 1 ~/.olddesktop)
    CDT=$(tail -n 1 ~/.olddesktop)
    DT=$(wmctrl -d|awk '{print $6}')
    if [ "$DT" != "$CDT" ] ;then
        echo $CDT >  ~/.olddesktop
        echo $DT >> ~/.olddesktop
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

And this command must be defined as an keyboard application shortcut.

```
wmctrl -o $(head -1 ~/.olddesktop)
```

Now you will be switched back to the viewport where you came from when you press your defined key combination (I used ALT-W).

`wmctrl must be installed. (apt-get install wmctrl)`

Comment: Didn't try it. but at least the script could use some optimization; it has a lot of unnecessary read- and write actions. Also note that it will fail on quick back- and forth (or further) movements.